# Css positioning: how to position a block/paragraph under another

Tags: html, css, css-position, floating

I have this html structure

```
<img class="media-object pull-left" src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
<h4 class="media-heading">Heading</h4>
<p>Paragraph lorem ipsum bla bla bla </p>
```

And I need this sort of positioning
[image]

That is, I always want the paragraph to appear under the image. The most basic solution would be to give the `h4` a `margin-bottom` sufficient to push the paragraph below the image (or give the `p` an equivalent `margin-top`).

Is there a better way to do this without knowing the image dimension and avoiding to use the margins to position the elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.pull-left {
 float: left;
}
p {
 clear: both;
}
```

You may want to make this a little more specific using classes or id's for the `<p>` tag, however.

Comment: thanks, I guess this is the way..but now if I want to push the `p` a little bit lower using `margin-top` this doesn't have any effect until I reach the distance in px from the heading instead from the img..so I'm back to my old problem..

Comment: Add padding to the top.  This affects the inside of the paragraph so should work.  May not be how you want it to work, though.

Comment: Actually, just tested adding margin to the bottom of picture (which feels more accurate to me), and that works.  http://jsfiddle.net/p82suhps/

Answer (score 1):

First you let the image float to the left, so the other two show up on the right side of the image.

The heading needs no further adjusting (in the demo it has a `margin-bottom: 0`, only to make sure that the margin doesn't already push the paragraph underneath the image).

The clear both sides of the paragraph, and it goes to the next line.

```
.pull-left {
    float: left;
}
p {
    clear: both;
}
```

And ofcourse [**the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7s9t8w2s/)

Answer (score 0):

an `<img>` is an inline element, therefore elements can be positioned next to it. like your header. to resolve this, you could wrap your `<img>` and `<h4>` inside a `<div>`

Comment: There is no need for an extra element, you can do it pure CSS, without altering the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can have the image and header in one div and then the paragraph in another. You can also try adding `padding-top:10px;` where you can replace `10px` with whatever will fit.